# snakemake LSF issues

Tags: python-3.x, lsf, snakemake

I have a pipeline which works just fine in the command line

```
snakemake -l --snakefile snakemake_example/sankefile_test9.txt
```

I would like to be able to use it on the cluster. The pipeline takes samples (specified in the config file), and runs a few steps of processing - this is an RNA-Seq pipeline. I've tried to submit to the cluster using these two different ways

#### First try

```
snakemake --snakefile sankefile_test9_config.txt --jobs 999 --cluster 'bsub -q bio -R "rusage[mem=4000]"'
```

#### Second try

```
snakemake --snakefile sankefile_test9_config.txt --cluster 'bsub -q bio' -j
```

which yielded the following output

> Provided cluster nodes: 48
>   Job counts:
>       count   jobs
>       1   all
>       2   collate_barcodes
>       2   correct_counts
>       2   count_reads
>       2   dedup_counts
>       2   extract_gz_samples
>       2   mark_duplicaticates
>       2   move_bc
>       2   run_cutadapt
>       2   star_mapping
>       19
>   rule extract_gz_samples:
>       input: cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R1.fastq.gz,   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R2.fastq.gz
>       output: cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R1.fastq,   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R2.fastq
>       wildcards: sample=cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1
>   Memory reservation is (MB): 2048
>   Memory Limit is (MB): 2048
>   rule extract_gz_samples:
>       input: cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R1.fastq.gz,   cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R2.fastq.gz
>       output: cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R1.fastq,   cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R2.fastq
>       wildcards: sample=cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393
>   Memory reservation is (MB): 2048
>   Memory Limit is (MB): 2048
>   Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
>   Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 257, in check_and_touch_output
>       wait_for_files(expanded_output, latency_wait=wait)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 341, in wait_for_files
>       latency_wait, "\n".join(get_missing())))
>   OSError: Missing files after 5 seconds:
>   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R1.fastq
>   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R2.fastq

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 517, in _wait_for_jobs
>       self.finish_job(active_job.job)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 426, in finish_job
>       super().finish_job(job, upload_remote=False)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 153, in finish_job
>       super().finish_job(job, upload_remote=upload_remote)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 111, in finish_job
>       self.dag.check_and_touch_output(job, wait=self.latency_wait)
>     File "/apps/RH6U4/python/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 259, in check_and_touch_output
>       raise MissingOutputException(str(e), rule=job.rule)
>   snakemake.exceptions.MissingOutputException: Missing files after 5 seconds:
>   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R1.fastq
>   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R2.fastq
>
> ^C^H^CTerminating processes on user request.
>   Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
>   Removing output files of failed job extract_gz_samples since they might be   corrupted:
>   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R1.fastq,   cluster_fastq/Zelzer_M_Spindle_M_1.R2.fastq
>   Removing output files of failed job extract_gz_samples since they might be corrupted:
>   cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R1.fastq, cluster_fastq/WT_M_DT_T_393.R2.fastq

At this point, the program seems to be stuck (see the `^C^H^C`, my break) - and if I check the jobs (in another session) using `bjobs`, there are no jobs on the queue.

Any idea why this is happening and how to debug it?

Comment: Did you try running with --dryrun first?

Comment: Could be a latency problem: try using "--latency-wait 100" on the command line

Answer (score 1):

We have had similar issues on our cluster -- see the issue on BitBucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/389/persistent-and-erroneous). I also found information in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/snakemake/latency-wait%7Csort:relevance/snakemake/4yIttyoNGK8/SYkRlnxqCQAJ) on the Google Group to be helpful.

In general, setting the --latency-wait parameter to 90 or 100 (per Eric C's suggestion) has sufficed for my workflows.